# Rails scope check for empty and null

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this scope trying to find specific records, but I just realized that it's checking for a null budget_id, but some of the records look empty not null and I'm not sure how to check for that (postgres).

Here's the current scope:

```
scope :working 0> { joins(:budget).where('scenarios.state is not null and (scenarios.budget_id is null or budgets.state not in (?))', ['implemented', 'archived']) }
```

The part that isn't working the the `scenarios.budget_id is null` How do I check if that is empty or null? I tried a coalesce, but the way I was doing it apparently was wrong because it wasn't checking for an integer which the budget_id is.

Comment: What would "empty" mean for an integer?

Comment: I would figure null which is why I feel like it should be working. I'm 95% sure that that is where the issue is at though after looking through the tests. There's nothing else that could make it fail.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw data? Or the SQL that ends up being used?

Comment: I assume the `0>` instead of `->` in the question is a typo?